# Freebase MQL, check if Subject is an Entity

Tags: freebase

I want to know if a subject is a freebase entity (a topic) or not
and i have to do this with several names (1258 names). It does not
matter of which type the topic is it just matters if something with
a special name exists in the freebase database as a topic (not a 
relation). The name could also be an alias.

So this is how far it is (Thx to Tom Morris)

```
[{
  "id": null,
  "t:type": "/common/topic",
  "type": [],
  "name": "Bill Gates"
}]
```

So there is only the part with the alias left.
The alias is optional. So from the example "Bill Gates" could
be a name OR an alias. If the name exists in one or both i want
to get a result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Changing your query to

```
[{
  "id": null,
  "type": [],
  "name": "Bill Gates"
}]
```

Will fix the initial error (because an object can, and usually does, have multiple topics) and you can then check to see if it has the type `/common/topic`.

More directly, you could use

```
[{
  "id": null,
  "t:type": "/common/topic",
  "type": [],
  "name": "Bill Gates"
}]
```

to only return the 60 topics which are in Freebase with that name.

Of course, they're everything from a dead guy to books to audio recordings to the person most people would associate with the name.  Are these really all equivalent for your purposes?

Also, if you instead searched for "William Gates," you wouldn't find the most famous one, because that's an alias for him, not the primary name.e

Comment: Yes that was one of my intentions to get the alias too, so that the name that im searching for can be a name of a topic or an alias of the topic.